# How can I see the processes structured by sessions and process groups?

Tags: linux, shell, job-control

As far as I know, linux kenerl has sessions and process groups concept, I want to see the sessions and groups, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

```
 ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm | less
 PID  PPID  PGID   SID COMMAND
    1     0     1     1 systemd
    2     0     0     0 kthreadd
    3     2     0     0 ksoftirqd/0
    5     2     0     0 kworker/0:0H
    6     2     0     0 kworker/u64:0
    8     2     0     0 migration/0


. . . . 
. . . . 
. . . . 
. . . . 

hit enter to see the next line

PID -  Process ID
PPID - Parent Process ID
PGIF - process group ID
SID - Session ID
```

for more check [ps man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)

If you would like to check specific PID then use this command:

```
ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm | grep <PID>
```

or

```
ps p <PID> o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm
```

Comment: or, for a specific pid without grepping: `ps p PID o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm`

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller very nice!! i will include it in the answer ;-)

Comment: It doesn't seem to group my processes by session, but just tell me SID and PGID

Comment: What do you mean by `It doesn't seem to group my processes by session`?